# VBSCRIPT: Find Text in a File and Email Log If It Finds Text

Tags: email, search, text, vbscript

I currently have a VBSCRIPT that will take the full contents of the error log and email it to a user, but I would like to modify it so it searches for "Load data encountered" and if it appears, to then email the Error.log otherwise, don't attach the log and send a message "Load was successful".
Any help would be appreciated!

**Contents of Error.log**

```
2017-04-24 15:35:13,429 DEBUG [AIF]: CommData.updateWorkflow - END
2017-04-24 15:35:13,429 DEBUG [AIF]: AIFUtil.callOdiServlet - START
2017-04-24 15:35:13,451 INFO  [AIF]: EssbaseService.loadData - START
2017-04-24 15:35:13,507 DEBUG [AIF]: appId:3, appType:ESSBASE, mcFlag:false, dataLoadMethod:CLASSIC_VIA_EPMI, mDataFlowNode:LOCAL, textDataLoad:N, isFccsLoad:false, isJournalLoad:false
2017-04-24 15:35:13,508 DEBUG [AIF]: LOAD_METHOD:ESSFILE, LOAD_TYPE:DATA, EXPORT_MODE:STORE_DATA, CREATE_DRILL_REGION:false, PURGE_DATA_FILE:true, BATCH_SIZE:10000
2017-04-24 15:35:13,629 INFO  [AIF]: cloudServiceType: Planning, Resolved user name for application access: epm_default_cloud_admin
2017-04-24 15:35:14,816 DEBUG [AIF]: Obtained connection to essbase cube: Finance
2017-04-24 15:35:14,818 DEBUG [AIF]: Resolved essbase rule file name for loading: AIF0069
2017-04-24 15:35:14,819 DEBUG [AIF]: Fetching rule file from essbase server for data loading: AIF0069
2017-04-24 15:35:14,824 INFO  [AIF]: Starting executeDataRuleFile...
2017-04-24 15:35:14,826 DEBUG [AIF]: Locked rule file: AIF0069
2017-04-24 15:35:14,827 INFO  [AIF]: Getting load buffer for ASO data load...
2017-04-24 15:35:14,828 INFO  [AIF]: Initializing load buffer [1]
2017-04-24 15:35:14,828 INFO  [AIF]: Successfully initialized the load buffer
2017-04-24 15:35:14,828 INFO  [AIF]: Loading data into cube using data file...
2017-04-24 15:35:14,844 INFO  [AIF]: purge data file: /u03/inbox/outbox/AQCONSOL_930.dat
2017-04-24 15:35:14,845 INFO  [AIF]: The load buffer [1] has been closed.
2017-04-24 15:35:14,845 INFO  [AIF]: **Load data encountered** the following errors:
| Error: 3303 | A99999 | "A99999","01","Functional","L000","Default Version","C10010","P0000","J00000","FY16","G00","Actual","[YearTotal].[Q1].[Jan]",100 |
2017-04-24 15:35:14,845 INFO  [AIF]: Load data failed.
2017-04-24 15:35:14,846 DEBUG [AIF]: Unlocked rule file: AIF0069
2017-04-24 15:35:14,846 ERROR [AIF]: Load data failed.
2017-04-24 15:35:14,853 INFO  [AIF]: EssbaseService.loadData - END (false)
2017-04-24 15:35:14,871 DEBUG [AIF]: AIFUtil.callOdiServlet - END
2017-04-24 15:35:14,871 FATAL [AIF]: Error in CommData.loadData
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4769, in loadData
RuntimeError: false
```

**Script So Far:**

```
fileEmail = "C:\Error.log"

intCount = 0  
Set objStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileEmail)  
Do Until objStream.AtEndOfStream  
sline = objStream.Readline  
If intCount = 0 Then  
objMessage.Subject = sline  
Else  
strMessage = strMessage & sline & vbcrlf   
End If  
intCount = intCount + 1  
Loop  

Const cdoAnonymous = 0 'Do not authenticate
Const cdoBasic = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
Const cdoNTLM = 2 'NTLM

strMessage = strMessage & vbcrlf

objMessage.From = "test@123.com" 
objMessage.To = "test@123.com" 

objMessage.TextBody = strMessage

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("Microsoft URL") = 2 

'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("Microsoft URL") = "smtp.secureserver.net"

'Type of authentication, NONE, Basic (Base64 encoded), NTLM
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("Microsoft URL") = cdoBasic

'Your UserID on the SMTP server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("Microsoft URL") = ""

'Your password on the SMTP server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("Microsoft URL") = ""

'Server port (typically 25)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("Microsoft URL") = 465 

'Use SSL for the connection (False or True)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("Microsoft URL") = True

'Connection Timeout in seconds (the maximum time CDO will try to establish a connection to the SMTP server)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("Microsoft URL") = 60

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

objMessage.Send

Set objStream = Nothing

'Delete File when finished

objFSO.DeleteFile fileprocesslog, True
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Trying to get the logic to work for searching the words "Load data encountered" in the error log and if it exists, then attach this to the email and send to someone.  If it doesn't exists, send an email without attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`InStr` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c(v=vs.84).aspx) returns the position of the first occurrence of one string within another. Apply it e.g. as follows:

```
sSearchFor   = "Load data encountered"
booFound     = False
sMessageSubj = "Log file empty"
fileEmail = "C:\Error.log"
intCount = 0
Set objStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileEmail)  
Do Until objStream.AtEndOfStream  
  sline = objStream.Readline  
  If intCount = 0 Then  
    sMessageSubj = sline  
  Else  
    strMessage = strMessage & sline & vbcrlf   
  End If
  booFound = booFound  Or ( Instr( 1, sline, sSearchFor, vbTextCompare) > 0)
  intCount = intCount + 1  
Loop
objStream.Close

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.From    = "test@123.com" 
objMessage.To      = "test@123.com" 
objMessage.Subject = sMessageSubj
If booFound Then
  objMessage.AddAttachment fileEmail
  strMessage = strMessage & vbcrlf
Else
  strMessage = "Load was successful" & vbcrlf
End If
objMessage.TextBody = strMessage
' ''' remote SMTP server configuration section Begin '''
' '''        configure remote SMTP server here       '''
' objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
' ''' remote SMTP server configuration section End   '''
objMessage.Send

Const cdoAnonymous = 0 'Do not authenticate
Const cdoBasic = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
Const cdoNTLM = 2 'NTLM
```

Read [*Sending email with CDO*](http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm) as well.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!